# Computing the nearest hermitian positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, oa.operator-algebras, nonlinear-optimization

The real case of finding the nearest semi-definite matrix in terms of the  Frobenius norm was solved by [Higham in 1988](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(88)90223-6).

*But is there any work on computing the nearest 
hermitian positive semi-definite of a complex matrix?*

*Is there any work for finding the nearest semi-definite matrix of a given hermitian matrix?*

*Are there any results in terms of other norms in the real and complex case?*

Comment: The nearest positive semidefinite matrix to a Hermitian matrix is just its positive semidefinite part (i.e., apply the spectral decomposition to it and then replace the negative eigenvalues by zeros). This is straightforward to prove for any unitarily-invariant norm, and in particular is thus true for the Frobenius norm.
For the nearest PSD matrix in the non-Hermitian complex case, the only part of the real proof that doesn't carry over obviously is the fact that the decomposition A = (A+A^*)/2 + (A-A)^*/2 is not orthogonal in the complex case (I'm not sure if this is a big problem or not).